How to get the output of the bash script inside a puppet file in the output from puppet
I am hoping that someone might be able to help me. I have a puppet script with some bash code inside it. I am trying to get the output of some echo commands to show in the puppet output so that I can see the order that the bash script is running.
The script looks like this:
# Add an XFRM interface
$xfrm_config = @("xfrm-config")
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

# Only configure `xfrm0` on the event that `eth0` has been configured 
if [ "\$\{IFACE\}" = "eth0" ] && [ "\$\{STATE\}" = "routable" ] && [ "\$\{AdministrativeState\}" = "configured" ] && [ "\$\{OperationalState\}" = "routable" ]; then

    # Remove the adapter if it already exists
    if ip link show xfrm0 > /dev/null 2>&1; then 
        ip link delete xfrm0 
    echo "step 1"
    fi

    # Add and activate the adapter, IP, and route
    ip link add xfrm0 type xfrm dev eth0 if_id 0xabcd 
  echo "step 2"
    ip address add ${host_server_net_mesh_vpn_ipv4_address}/32 dev xfrm0 
  echo "step 3"
    ip link set xfrm0 up 
  echo "step 4"
    ip route add ${peer_server_net_mesh_vpn_ipv4_address}/32 dev xfrm0 
  echo "step 5"

fi
| xfrm-config

file { $xfrm_config_path:
  ensure  => file,
  owner   => 'root',
  group   => 'root',
  mode    => '0755',
  content => $xfrm_config,
}
~> exec { 'add-xfrm-interface':
  command     => $xfrm_config_path,
  path        => '/usr/bin',
  provider    => 'shell',
  environment => ['IFACE=eth0', 'STATE=routable', 'AdministrativeState=configured', 'OperationalState=routable'],
  logoutput   => true,
}

If anyone has any ideas on how I can get the echos commands and the bash debug to show when I am running the puppet command to run this script it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Are you already using debug and verbosity flags?

I would expect the logoutput => true that you already have in your Exec resource to cause any output from the Exec's command to be forwarded to Puppet's output.  If you don't see that happening then you could try writing the messages to the script's standard error instead of its standard output, but I don't think that should be necessary.

With that said, your script looks problematic.  Note that if you want to use escape sequences such as \$ in your heredoc then you need to enable them.  Note also that there should be no need to escape the { or } character, at least not at the Puppet level.  Additionally, within your heredoc are references to Puppet variables, $host_server_net_mesh_vpn_ipv4_address and $peer_server_net_mesh_vpn_ipv4_address, that do not appear elsewhere in the script (as presented).

Also, it's a bit weird that you make the shell script do logic based on environment variables provided for it by Puppet, instead of just performing that logic in the Puppet code, and acting appropriately at that level.

Do you need to make decisions in your Puppet code based on the command’s output? Does the command make the client lose the network connection it uses to contact the Puppet master? Where do you want the script’s output? A file on the client? In a Puppet report? Both? Why do you notify Exec['add-xfrm-interface'] instead of a require relationship? Why do you need to embed the constants $host_server_net_mesh_vpn_ipv4_address and $peer_server_net_mesh_vpn_ipv4_address into the script instead of reading command‑line arguments $1 and $2?
